# XSL values detecting string in URL

Tags: xml, string, url, xslt

I have a multi-language site with a url structure like this: `www.mysite/en/home.htm` or `www.mysite/es/home.htm` (for english and spanish versions).

In this home.htm I have a table data from an xml files.
The headers of this table, `<th>`, are into a xsl file.

I would like to dinamically change these  values depending on the language that I would detect by that `/es/` in the URL.

- If URL = www.mysite/en/home.htm then
- Description
- Game Type
- ....
- If URL = www.mysite/es/home.htm than
- Descripción
- Tipo De Juego
- ....

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'www.mysite/es/home.htm '"/>

 <my:headings>
  <h lang="en">
    <description>Description</description>
    <gameType>Game Type</gameType>
  </h>
  <h lang="es">
    <description>Descripción</description>
    <gameType>Tipo De Juego</gameType>
  </h>
 </my:headings>

 <xsl:variable name="vHeadings" select="document('')/*/my:headings/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="vLang" select=
    "substring-before(substring-after($pUrl, '/'), '/')"/>

     <table>
       <thead>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$vHeadings[@lang=$vLang]/description"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$vHeadings[@lang=$vLang]/gameType"/></td>
       </thead>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted headings**:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <td>Descripción</td>
      <td>Tipo De Juego</td>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**Note**: In a real-world app you may want to put the language-specific data in a separate XML file (or even in files -- one per language) -- in such a case you only need to slightly change the call to the `document()` function in this code.

**UPDATE**:

The OP has indicated in a comment that the use of `document()` is forbidden in his environment.

**Here is the same solution with a slight modification to work without using `document()`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'www.mysite/es/home.htm '"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfHeadings">
  <h lang="en">
    <description>Description</description>
    <gameType>Game Type</gameType>
  </h>
  <h lang="es">
    <description>Descripción</description>
    <gameType>Tipo De Juego</gameType>
  </h>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vHeadings" select="ext:node-set($vrtfHeadings)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="vLang" select=
    "substring-before(substring-after($pUrl, '/'), '/')"/>

     <table>
       <thead>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$vHeadings[@lang=$vLang]/description"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$vHeadings[@lang=$vLang]/gameType"/></td>
       </thead>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This sounds good. But ubfortunately I'm in a DNN module and I suppose I have some limitations. I get this error: "DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at (0,0). ---> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at (0,0). at vHeadings(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)..."

Comment: @user1345999: So do what the message says: enable this setting. Another way is to place the `h` elements inside an `xsl:variable` and then convert this RTF to a regular tree using the `ext:node-set()` extension function.

Comment: @user1345999: I updated my answer (look at the end) with a solution that doesn't use `document()`

Comment: ok, no more errors, but lang don't change. <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'www.mysite/es-es/home.htm '"/> i have label in spanish; if i have <xsl:param name="pUrl" select="'www.mysite/en-us/home.htm '"/>
I have label in english. The only difference is "en-us" instead of "en" but i have changed "<xsl:variable name="vrtfHeadings">
  <h lang="en-us">" as well.

Comment: Is there a way to have pUrl dynamically?

Comment: @user1345999: Of course, `pUrl` is defined as global/external parameter. Every XSLT processor has its own APIs to invoke a transformation, passing (external) parameters to it. Whatever value is specified in the XSLT stylesheet for this parameter is only the *default* value. It will be used only if no value for this parameter has been specified from the invoker of the transformation. Also, most XSLT processors allow specifying and passing string-valued parameters when they are invoked from the command-line. Just read the documentation of your XSLT processor and search for examples.